# Javascript calculate subtotal and total from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

First of all, I'm sorry if this question has already been asked and solved before, but I cant find the exact answer/solution for my problem.

My question is, how do I calculate grand-total if a user changes quantity and/or selects more that 1 product?  My product item list and value is from mysql.

Here's my form details:

```
<?php $price = 10.00;?>
<input name="qty_<?php echo $obj->product_code;?>" type="text" id="qty<?php echo $obj->product_code;?>" value="0" size="2" onkeyup="calculate()">

<input name="subtotal_<?php echo $obj->product_code;?>" type="text" id="subtotal_<?php echo $obj->product_code;?>" value="0.00" size="7" readonly>

<input name="qty_<?php echo $obj->product_code;?>" type="text" id="qty<?php echo $obj->product_code;?>" value="0" size="2" onkeyup="calculate()">

<input name="subtotal_<?php echo $obj->product_code;?>" type="text" id="subtotal_<?php echo $obj->product_code;?>" value="0.00" size="7" readonly>

<input name="grandtotal" type="text" id="grandtotal" value="0.00" readonly>
```

I'm using my php/mysql results value for my input field name/id, as it's easier for me to identify/pass the value when submitted.

Here's my Javascript:

```
function calculate()
{
    var quantity = document.getElementById('<?php echo $obj->product_code;?>').value;
    var currprice = <?php echo $obj->product_code.$obj->product_price;?>;
    var total = quantity * currprice;
    document.getElementById('subtotal_<?php echo $obj->product_code;?>').value = total.formatMoney(2,',','.');
}
```

So, how do I calculate the subtotal from each product and display it at grand total text field?
I've already searched Google but have not been able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) **Using the right ID's**

The id's of the quantity fields do not match with the `getElementById` in the function. It should start with "qty_", not directly the product code. Also, for the sake of regularity, change the id's in the `<input>`'s from "qty" to "qty_".

2) **The right structure**

The html you use now, has double quantity and subtotal `<input>` fields with the same ID. This causes Javascript to be unable to access these values. Make sure you distinguish between the names and ID's of these input fields.

***PHP***:

```html
$products = array(
  array("price"=>10, "code"=>"product1"),
  array("price"=>25, "code"=>"product2")
);

foreach($products as $key => $productInfo) {
  /* echo a hidden field with the price per product (for calculation later) */
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="price_'. $productInfo["code"] .'" id="price_'. $productInfo["code"] .'" value="'. $productInfo["price"] .'" />';

  /* echo the quantity field for this product */
  echo '<input class="qty" name="'. $productInfo["code"] .'" id="'. $productInfo["code"] .'" type="text" value="0" size="2" onkeyup="calculate()">';

  /* echo the subtotal field for this product */
  echo '<input name="sub_'. $productInfo["code"] .'" type="text" id="sub_'. $productInfo["code"] .'" value="0.00" size="7" readonly>';
}

/* echo the field for total price */
echo '<input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0.00" />';
```

This results in sets of three input fields per product:

- One for the price per product (id="price_THEPRODUCTCODE")
- One for the quantity (id="THEPRODUCTCODE")
- And one for the subtotal (id="sub_THEPRODUCTCODE")

***Javascript***

I suggest using the jQuery library for faster and easier collection of the data from the input fields here.

The function would then be:

```js
function calculate() {
  var total = 0;
  
  // for each quantity field:
  $("input.qty").each(function() {
  
    // get product code
    var productCode = $(this).attr("id");
    
    // get price per product
    var price = $("#price_"+productCode).val();
    
    // get quantity
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    
    // calculate subtotal
    var subtotal = (price*quantity);
    
    // put new subtotal back in the input field
    $("#sub_"+productCode).val(subtotal);
    
    // add subtotal to total
    total += subtotal;
  
  });

  // put total in the input field of total
  $("#total").val(total);
 
}
```

Comment: Thx for the neat answer. I will let u know when im home & test it. I'll get back to u later. :)

Comment: thank you for your help. Very clear and easy solution. Thank you for sharing some knowledge. I really appreciate it. Big thank you once again for you. Problem solved!

Comment: You're welcome! :)  I learned a lot on SO too, so glad to return the favour.